# Export csv or xml file from a dataset in Postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, csv, export

I would like to export a dataset of a table in a csv or xml file, depending on what is easier. 
I'm using Postgresql DBMS. Anyone knows how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html),  [`\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)

Answer (score 0):

Use copy command or run query with psql and redirect STD OUT into file. Where are some other methods exists as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY TableName TO 'D:\demo.csv'  DELIMITER AS ',';
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this but I got a Permission Error. 
How can I use STDOUT into COPY statement togheter with 'D:\demo.csv' ?

Comment: Permission error means you not have enough permission to create file in d:.  Change drive if you have another options or give enough access to your D:\